# Is it possible to get a list of suggestion comments from a given google file in a google drive account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file in my google drive account that has many suggestions created from users in "Suggesting" mode. Suggestions are comments, but made in suggesting mode. When in "Suggesting" mode the user can not make edits, but can instead make suggestions, and when a suggestion is created it creates a comment such as: Replace the word "Hello" with "Hi".

Google Drive API has a Comments API that will allow me to list all comments created for a file. However, it does not list "suggestion" comments. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list

Is there a way to get a list of suggestion comments for a file, instead of just comments?

Comment: To my knowledge the is no other endpoint to get the list of suggestion comments. However you can file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/) for that.

Comment: I have not been able to find anything, and I read and tried most of the DRIVE APIs that might accomplish retrieving a list of suggestion comments. Thanks for the link for the feature request page.

Comment: @corey I'm also interested in this functionality and was wondering whether you filed a feature request for it?

Comment: @alex No I didn't file a feature request. The existing list is long.

Comment: @alex do you need the specific suggestion comment text, or do you need know if a suggestion exists? I found a work around, though I am not using it because the source could change causing the solution to no longer work.